# How to align my rectangles in Java FX GridPane from my Main.java file?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm trying to make a java Sudoku Game. I cannot align my Sudoku input rectangles. They are being shifted away because of the buttons at the bottom of the input board. How can I align the rectangles like my `expected.jpg` in my `Main.java`. I want to make my `Buttons` and `Input Rectangles` through the `Main.java` file only. If it is not possible to make the alignment though `Main.java`, please let me know. Thanks

`expected.jpg`:

[image]

`what_i_get.jpg`:

[image]

`Main.java`:

```
package application;

import java.util.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class Main extends Application {
    int[][] original_map;
    StackPane[][] screen_buttons = new StackPane[10][10];

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,700);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setHgap(10);
        root.setVgap(10);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 700);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    // USING SUDOKU.java to build the Sudoku Game
        Sudoku map = new Sudoku();
    // STORING the sudoku game in the 2x2 array
        this.original_map = map.make_game();

        for (int y=0;y<9;y++) {
            for (int x=0;x<9;x++) {
                screen_buttons[y][x] = new StackPane();
                Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(30,30);
                rec.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.WHITE);
                rec.setStyle("-fx-arc-height: 10; -fx-arc-width: 10;");
                Label label = new Label(Integer.toString(this.original_map[y][x]));
                screen_buttons[y][x].getChildren().addAll(rec, label);
                root.add(screen_buttons[y][x], x, y);
            }
        }

        Button[] function_buttons = new Button[4];
        String[] function_id = {"Hint", "Clear", "Pause", "Check"};
        int pos = 0;
        for (Button b : function_buttons) {
            if (function_id[pos] == "Hint") {
                b = new Button(function_id[pos]);
                root.add(b, 1, pos+10);
            } else if (function_id[pos] == "Clear"){
                b = new Button(function_id[pos]);
                root.add(b, 1, pos+10);
            } else if (function_id[pos] == "Pause"){
                b = new Button(function_id[pos]);
                root.add(b, 1, pos+10);
            } else {
                b = new Button(function_id[pos]);
                root.add(b, 6, 11);
            }
            b.setStyle("-fx-pref-width: 100px; -fx-pref-height: 50px;");
            pos++;
        }

        Button[] click_buttons = new Button[9];
        pos = 1;
        for (int y=10;y<=12;y++) {
            for (int x=2;x<=4;x++) {
                click_buttons[pos-1] = new Button(Integer.toString(pos));
                root.add(click_buttons[pos-1], x, y);
                click_buttons[pos-1].setStyle("-fx-pref-width: 50px; -fx-pref-height: 50px;");
                pos++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, there are only 9 x 9 grids, why is `screen_buttons` a 10 by 10 array?

Comment: @Jai right my bad. Was suppose to write 9x9

Comment: I do not see any `ColumnConstraints` or `RowConstraints` in your code. Without them, the `GridPane` will automatically resize your columns and rows based on available space.

Comment: Also, it would be most helpful if you were to post a [mcve] so we can compile, test, and improve the code.

Comment: @Zephyr How do I add the `ColumnConstraints` or `RowConstraints` in the `Main.java`?

Comment: Please update your question to include a complete example of your current application that we can run on our systems (see the [mcve] article for tips on doing so). I am also working on a sample for you, but being able to modify your existing code may be more helpful.

Comment: I have uploaded my project in this zip file. URL = `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ujye85HK_poxNQqnVRgAACeYfqTjX5Nm/view?usp=sharing`

Comment: No need for the entire project. What is needed is mcve, as commented by @Zephyr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common strategy to gain better control over layout, is to sub-divide it into smaller, simpler to manage containers, each having its own layout manager. 
In this case, start by separating the game and it's controls into two containers as proposed by [Jai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52846161/3992939) :

```
public class Main extends Application {

    StackPane[][] screen_buttons = new StackPane[9][9];

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

       //container for game
       BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);

        for (int y=0;y<screen_buttons.length;y++) {
            for (int x=0;x<screen_buttons[y].length;x++) {
                screen_buttons[y][x] = new StackPane();
                Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(30,30);
                rec.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.WHITE);
                rec.setStyle("-fx-arc-height: 10; -fx-arc-width: 10;");
                Label label = new Label("0");
                screen_buttons[y][x].getChildren().addAll(rec, label);
                grid.add(screen_buttons[y][x], x, y);
            }
        }

        //container for controls
        GridPane controls = new GridPane();

        Button[] function_buttons = new Button[4];
        String[] function_id = {"Hint", "Clear", "Pause", "Check"};
        int pos = 0;
        for (Button b : function_buttons) {
            if (function_id[pos] == "Hint") {
                b = new Button(function_id[pos]);
                controls.add(b, 1, pos+10);
            } else if (function_id[pos] == "Clear"){
                b = new Button(function_id[pos]);
                controls.add(b, 1, pos+10);
            } else if (function_id[pos] == "Pause"){
                b = new Button(function_id[pos]);
                controls.add(b, 1, pos+10);
            } else {
                b = new Button(function_id[pos]);
                controls.add(b, 6, 11);
            }
            b.setStyle("-fx-pref-width: 100px; -fx-pref-height: 50px;");
            pos++;
        }

        Button[] click_buttons = new Button[9];
        pos = 1;
        for (int y=10;y<=12;y++) {
            for (int x=2;x<=4;x++) {
                click_buttons[pos-1] = new Button(Integer.toString(pos));
                controls.add(click_buttons[pos-1], x, y);
                click_buttons[pos-1].setStyle("-fx-pref-width: 50px; -fx-pref-height: 50px;");
                pos++;
            }
        }

        root.setCenter(grid);
        root.setBottom(controls);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for expressing this into actual example (:

Comment: Thanks, it helped

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems (major and minor ones) here.

Firstly, `screen_buttons` is declared as `StackPane[10][10]`, which can potentially give you problem later.

Secondly, I have no idea why you created two root nodes and two scenes. It would work, but totally unnecessary.

Thirdly, your `GridPane` is used as the common root for the display grid and the control buttons. All the buttons below is affecting the column widths at the grid on top. You need to separate these two. You could use a `BorderPane` containing two `GridPane` child nodes - one for the display and another for control.

Lastly, doing `Label label = new Label(Integer.toString(this.original_map[y][x]))` is going to make your grid display *static* values. While this looks great for grids pre-generated with values, this can be a problem when the player places a number on the grid. Of course, you could *manually* set the text of the corresponding grid when the user does an action, but this would make it redundant to keep 2 arrays here.

Comment: I tried ur thirdly method, but I'm not able to align the second GirdPane elements properly.

Comment: Thanks, thirdly helped